# Parsing XML API data result from Plesk

Tags: php, xml, api, plesk

I try to get domain name from Plesk API result XML data as below:

```
<packet version="1.6.7.0">
<site-alias>
<get>
<result>
<status>ok</status>
<info>
<name>example.com</name>         
</info>
</result>
<result>
<status>ok</status>
<info>
<name>domain.net</name>         
</info>
</result>
</get>
</site-alias>
</packet>
```

using

```
$xml= simplexml_load_string($response);
echo $xml['site-alias']['get']['result'][0]['name'];
```

if there is more better way to do so, please advice, thanks.

Comment: Please do not post links to images of text. Post the actual text.

Comment: thanks, I try to do so but inserting xml always get need to indent 4 spaces despite I have done so, please advice

Comment: What do you actually want to get? Both example.com and domain.net?

Comment: Yes @Chris actually more value but at this time I will need to print this value. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to get the values using [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php).

To get only 1 value, you could for example do it like this:

```
// Get 1 using SimpleXMLElement
echo $xml->{"site-alias"}->get->result->info->name;

// Get 1 using xpath
echo $xml->xpath('/packet/site-alias/get/result[1]/info/name')[0];
```

To get multiple values you could do it like this:

```
// Get multiple using SimpleXMLElement
$items = $xml->{"site-alias"}->get->result;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item->info->name . "<br>";
}

// Get multiple using xpath
$items = $xml->xpath('/packet/site-alias/get/result/info/name');
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item . "<br>";
}
```

The [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) has a method [__toString](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php) so you can echo the string content.
The [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method returns an array, so you can get the first value using index 0.

A short way to get your value could be:

```
echo $xml->xpath('//name')[0];
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/P13JS)

Comment: Thank you. I actually just solve the issue, the problem seem that the key/atribute was having hyphen that causing error,

$xml= simplexml_load_string($response);

    foreach($xml->{"site-alias"}->get->result as $result) {
         echo $result->id . " -> " . $result->info->name . "<br>";
    }